# Is it possible to declare an alias for an Assembly Part in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-assembly, mvcrazor

When loading an Assembly from a `dll`-file with `AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(file);` and adding it as an ApplicationPart via the ApplicationPartManager is it possible to declare an alias for this Application Part like you could do when passing references to the CSharp compiler?

My problem is that I have two Application Parts containing classes with the same name and namespace, so I need an oppurtunity to differ these when using them in a view.

Comment: what would you *do* with that alias? what does an alias even *mean* to something loaded at runtime? import alias (extern alias) is entirely a compiler concept

Comment: I want to use this in a Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor context. More precisely I want to add the dynamically loaded assembly as an application part. Assumed the loaded assembly would contain a class with the full name "My.Namespace.Model.Product", I want to reference this class in a View with "MyAlias::My.Namespace.Model.Product".